# importing matplotlib ipython with anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, ipython, anaconda, canopy

I am programming python in IPython and I used to use Canopy as a package for libraries to fuel iPython. 
Recently I switched to Anaconda instead of Canopy but since then I can't import matplotlib or numpy in mij ipython. (I only tested these as I use them regulary)
The path is going to the old Canopy installation which I deleted and doesnt exist anymore. I reinstalled Anaconda and iPython several times but nothing changed.

When I try to import matplotlib with a .py file and execute it in the terminal it works perfectly and uses te anaconda files.

How can I fix this as I want ipython to look in the right file.

Comment: Found it out myself finally with this trick: import sys
sys.path.remove("path/to/Modules")
print sys.path

Comment: Is the PYTHONPATH environment variable set? That could cause this.